# Image overlay design with susy/compass

Tags: susy-compass, compass-sass

I would to use compass/susy and I need to make the same thing as pure css.
This is an example : http://www.lycee-celony.com/

I need that text be positioned on to the image, in the slideshow.
How can I do that with these tools or others from compass?

For image, I can use :

```
.adaptable-img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

My need is about the grid management for that, and in the technical nesting  for these blocks.

Thanks

EDIT1: My css classic code that work for now:

```
@include at-breakpoint($desktop) {/*    //Dimensions pour les pc*/
    aside.DiapoHP{
        img{@include adaptable-img;}
}
    #transparency{ @include span-columns($desktop);}
    #contenu-diapo{@include span-columns($desktop);}
}

    #transparency{
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 $orange;/*Couleur du fond*/
    height:em(65px);
    bottom:em(70px); 
    left:em(12px);
    position:absolute;
    z-index:15;
    @include opacity(0.6);
    }
    #contenu-diapo {
      position: relative;
      left: em(10px);
      color: white;
      z-index: 20;


      h2 {
        color: white;
        padding: em(5px);
        font-family: $AristaFont;
         position: inherit;
         bottom:em(85px);
      }
      a {

        text-decoration: none;
      }
    }
```

For this html:

```
<aside class="diapoHP">
    <div id="transparency"></div>
    <div id="contenu-diapo">
    <h2>blblblb</h2>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: It's not clear what tools you need, or why. Are you having trouble creating the overlay? What have you tried? It looks to me like a pretty simple matter of positioning, though that depends some on how you build the slideshow itself. What help do you hope to get from Susy/Compass?

Comment: ok i figure it out with my classic css, but perhaps compass/susy provide better solutions ?